# Move inside UL and change LI class if has .has_children class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to move inside a UL element and change LI and children UL class if `.has_children` is present. See this example:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="first current parent">Link1</li>
    <li class="parent">Link2</li>
    <li class="has_children parent"><a href="#">Link3</a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
            <li class="first parent">SubItem1</li>
            <li class="last parent">SubItem2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here when I found `has_children` I should change by `dropdown` just in the parent or root LI. Then the UL with class `dropdown` that has `has_children` parent should be changed for `dropdown-menu dropdown-megamenu`. This need to be iterative until latest nested level. The result should be like this:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active">Link1</li>
    <li class="">Link2</li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-close-others="true" data-hover="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" >Link3</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-megamenu">
            <li>SubItem1</li>
            <li>SubItem2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I tried this code to move inside elements:

```
$.each("ul.nav > li"), function(index, element) {
    console.log($(this).text());
}
```

But didn't work, can any give me some help or push?

Comment: This short snippet has several syntax errors.

Comment: @undefined can you point me in the right direction? Or what you mean with `several syntax errors`?

Comment: The `)` after `> li"` should be at the very end of the code to make the syntax correct. But then what you're doing is iterating over the characters in the string. You probably intended to fetch elements using that selector, in which case, you'd just do `$("ul.nav > li").each(function() {...});`

Comment: @cookiemonster yes, I'm just iterating trough names for testing if I'm right but I see I'm bad. So after iterates trough each LI how I get the elements inside each one? Should I made a Plunker for testing purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood the question correctly you want to change all the classNames, if this is the case instead of using `>` (*child*) selector you can use the descendant selector:

```
$("ul.nav li").each(function (index, element) {
    var $this = $(this),
        cls = '';

    if ($this.hasClass('current')) 
    {
        cls = 'active';
    } 
    else if ($this.hasClass('has_children')) 
    {
        cls = 'dropdown';
        $this.children('.dropdown')
             .attr('class', 'dropdown-menu dropdown-megamenu')
             .end()
             .children('a')
             .attr({
                'data-close-others': 'true',
                'data-hover'       : 'dropdown',
                'data-toggle'      : 'dropdown',
                'class'            : 'dropdown-toggle' 
             });
    } 

    $this.attr('class', cls);
});
```

Please note that I have used the `attr` method for resetting the class attribute's value, if you want to add/remove certain classNames you can use the `addClass`/`removeClass` methods instead.

Comment: Excellent, this is exactly what I tried to do without success

Comment: Hey, I miss something in the main code and it is related to the `<a> element where changes was maded. Can you take a look and add support for change parameters also in the `<a>` element?

Comment: @ReynierPM I have updated the code using `end` and `attr` method.

Comment: Smarter answer that what I though about using `.find()` with `$this`, thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I got it right. But I think that I'm close. Try using somethink like this recursive function:

```
$(function(){
    doIt( $('li', '.nav') );
});

var doIt = function($element){
    $e = $element || null;
    $e.each(function(){
        if( $(this).hasClass('has_children') ){
            $(this).attr('class', 'dropdown');
            $(this).children().attr('class', 'dropdown-menu dropdown-megamenu').children().each(function(){
                $(this).removeAttr('class');
            });
        }
    });
    this($e.next());
};
```

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/h6t7t/)